# Как регуляркой убрать кавычки вокруг букв в середине текста?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, текст

Как регуляркой убрать кавычки вокруг букв в середине этого текста:

```
'don't mess around','can't medium',
```

Нужно чтоб осталось вот так:

```
'dont mess around','cant medium',
```

Пробую через регулярные выражения - заменить строку  и меняю на пустоту вот такой регуляркой:

```
\w(')\w
```

Но получаю что регулярка захватывает и удаляем еще и по одной букве вокруг кавычки:

```
'do mess around','ca medium',
```

Comment: Язык программирования?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если синтаксис позволяет, то

```
(?<=\w)'(?=\w)
```

Иначе надо заменять

```
(\w)'(\w)
```

в зависимости от синтаксиса на

```
$1$2
```

или

```
\1\2
```

Comment: спасибо . сделал так и заработало:  (?<=\w)(')(?=\w)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```
\b'\b
```

Замените пустой строкой.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/BGvpYz/1).

Так как `'` не является букво-цифровым символом и символом нижнего подчёркивания, границы слов по обеим сторонам от `'` требуют наличия букво-цифрового символа или символа нижнего подчёркивания.